# How does this operation make a relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, symmetry

I don't get what is the function so $x = +$ and $- y$ so there's two $y$?
or does it mean $x = x + y$ and $x = x - y$. I don't know how to read this and what would its relation look like? $\{...(1,-1),(2,-2)...\}$etc? and cause of that I don't understand the explanation of why its symmetric and why its not anti-symmetric.

[image: problemimage]

Answer (score 1):

No operation involved here.

One defines the relation $R$ in the following way:

$$x \equiv_R y \iff x = \pm y$$

This means: either $x = y$ or $x = -y$

For example:

$$3 \equiv_R 3$$
$$3 \equiv_R -3$$

In fact, we can write this relation as:

$$R = \{(a,a) \in \mathbb{R^2}\} \cup \{(a,-a) \in \mathbb{R^2}\} $$

Comment: so both (3,3) and (3,-3) are part of the relation?

Comment: Yes, (-3,3) and (-3,-3) too

Comment: so its like you get two outputs at the same time

Comment: Yup. This relation does not define a function, if that's where you want to go.

Comment: The relation can be written $x \equiv_R y \iff |x| = |y|$ and thus belongs to a very common class of equivalence relations defined through $x \sim y \iff f(x) = f(y)$ for a fixed function $f$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to define a relation, that is, we are defining how two real numbers relate to each other via a definition (somewhat similar to how we define order relationship in the real numbers).

$$x \equiv_R y \iff x=y \text{ or } x=-y$$

For example, $1 \equiv_R -1$ and $1 \equiv_R 1$

Can you see why it does not satisfy anti-symmetry?